# Using authorization http header in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, header, angular5

I am trying to see what's in an API URL however it request basic authorization http header. how do i use the header to watch the URL directly from Chrome.

Comment: I don't know about Chrome, but Firefox has a REST extension, that lets you craft any HTTP request, including headers.

Comment: What is the name of such extension @roy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the answer to your problem, I use this architecture:

Press Crt+Shift+I:

[image]