# How to programatically display authorization header in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090147/5675125 However this is only a manual way.

I am using Laravel GraphQL playground and I need to add the Authorization header in manually each time.

I want to create a plugin that when clicked will paste the or display the authorisation header to minimise the steps I need to take.

Comment: What do you mean by "paste or display" the authorization header? Where will it get the header from, where will it paste it to or where will it display it?

Comment: @derpirscher - At the moment, I have to go to the dev console, then go to headers and then copy that information to paste into the textfield on playground.